# Error using PSEXEC to start a file on a remote computer

Tags: batch-file, psexec, remote-connection

I have created a small script that initiates **PSEXEC** to run a file (a registry key) on a remote computer that is in the domain; however, when I run the script I receive an error indicating that "the system cannot find the file specified."

Below is my script:

```
@echo off
psexec \\PRECDP19425 -u PRECDP19425\WAKE -p <password> -h -i -d C:\Users\WAKE\Documents\AllowNetwork.reg
pause
```

I have double-checked the location to make sure I wasn't losing my mind and typed something incorrectly, yet that doesn't seem to be the case. The path is correct, I'm just not sure what is causing the script to fail.

The exact error I receive is:

> PsExec could not start C:\Users\etc on PRECDP19425
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The path in the error is not the path in your batch file?  You likely need `reg import c:\xxx\xxx.reg` as the command.

Comment: Does the file exist on your computer or the remote computer?

Comment: @AlexK. The path in the error is the same as the path I input in the batch file.

Comment: @Squashman The file exists on the remote computer in the Users\Documents folder.

Comment: You need to specify the executable that runs the reg file. `REG.exe IMPORT C:\path\FileName.reg`

Comment: @AlexK. You are the man! I don't know what I was thinking because I know reg import only imports on a local machine. Forgot I was running in psexec! Running reg import into my script through psexec worked perfect! I really appreciate the help.

If you guys can post as an answer I will gladly upvote or whatever it is.

Comment: @Squashman  Yup! Just tried Alex's advice and it worked. Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C:\Users\WAKE\Documents\AllowNetwork.reg` is not a valid command line because a .reg file is not an executable, you need to pass it to reg.exe:

```
REG IMPORT C:\Users\WAKE\Documents\AllowNetwork.reg
```